# Why aren't one-character long keywords standard?

Tags: parsing, compilation

Based on my understanding of parsing, the compiler must look at the surrounding tokens of the one it is parsing to determine exactly which keyword/operator it is (eg. when parsing a '!' token, the compiler must look forward to see whether it is just the '!' operator or the "!=" operator) and this slows down the parsing.

Considering that there are plenty of ASCII characters not used by mainstream languages as keywords and operators, is there any particular reason why one-character long operators aren't commonly used or is it merely convention? Wouldn't using them improve compilation efficiency?

Comment: *plenty of ASCII characters* Extended ASCII is only 256 characters (one of which is NULL, and at least a dozen others are non-prinitable). That's not a lot of identifiers.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes it isn't a lot but even if not everything could be represented with one character, wouldn't it still be better for most of the commonly-used ones to be?

Comment: I don't see any advantage to doing so. There are already many one character identifiers used (x or i for loops, for example). Being terse leads to complexity - code becomes harder to read, understand and maintain. Modern compilers seem to be fast enough in most cases, and optimization does a lot of work that shorter identifiers wouldn't improve. This sounds more like a theoretical discussion question rather than a specific programming question.

Comment: @KenWhite Could you please share anything specific about the question I could improve? I thought it was relevant to language/compiler design and is specific (_Wouldn't using them improve compilation efficiency?_ is straightforward I think).

Comment: This might be a good question for a different site (such as Computer Science). SO is designed for specific questions related to actual problems you're having with programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). This doesn't seem to be specific in that regard - it's more of a theoretical discussion.

Comment: There are indeed programming languages that use many very short, often single-character, operators, and so on. APL comes to mind. However, most people prefer languages that are closer to how humans express mathematical and logical concepts.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your advice, is there a way to move the question over there without simply deleting it from here and reposting there?

Comment: You can try flagging it and asking a moderator to migrate it, but there is no way for normal users to move it. You can always [edit] it, select and copy all the text, cancel the edit, paste it into a new question at the other site, and then delete it here. You'd only need to add a title and tags at the other site. Don't forget to delete it here, though - multi-posting the same question across sites is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @KenWhite: Another site where this would be even more on topic is the new https://langdev.stackexchange.com/ - Programming Language Design and Implementation.  (And yeah, usually your best bet is to delete here, repost elsewhere.  Not much here in comments that's worth bothering moderators with a migration request.  Except the key point that parsing costs a minimal amount of time vs. other steps, especially with optimization enabled. [Why are there so few C compilers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/273698) - the optimizer is most of the codebases of compilers worth using.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Hadn't noticed that one. I'll have to take a look at it so I'm familiar with its guidelines. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @KenWhite: Cheers.  I found it via hot network questions a few months ago when a few questions popped up.  (Question number 1873 was the earliest one I commented on, so that's pretty early in the site's history I guess.)